# Can I block a button?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a DatePicker() and button in a ControlView, when I click on the button it jump to a function where i work with the date i choose in the DatePicker(which spins), the problem is while is datePicker spining and i click the button it doesn't choose the date and it jump to function without choosing the date. Is posibble while is spining the datepicker to block the button?Or it can be another way?

Thanks for answers

Comment: A typical UI would show datepicker only when needed - so you could block the button (enabled = NO) while picker is shown and vice-versa.

Comment: I just built one to fire on UIControlEventAllEvents and discovered that the date picker tells you nothing about it's state before it stops animating, only then do you get (only) UIControlEventValueChanged.  Really sad.

Comment: I just tried adding a swipeGestureRecognizer to the picker with cancelsTouchesInView = NO;  Target/selector doesn't fire.  Tried adding it to the parent view.  Works on the parent, not on the date picker.  +1 for the really hard question.  Sorry I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The `UIDatePicker` control will send an action method when the user has finished rotating the control (for the event `UIControlEventValueChanged`).  You could use this action method to *enable* the button so that the button can only be pressed after the user has completed picking a date.

See [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html):

> When properly configured, a UIDatePicker object sends an action
>   message when a user finishes rotating one of the wheels to change the
>   date or time; the associated control event is
>   UIControlEventValueChanged.

Comment: But what event should trigger the disabling of the button? There's nothing that I can think of.

Comment: @rmaddy It would be disabled by default and can be disabled on perhaps `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: But what if the user spins the picker and the button gets enabled. Now the user spins again. Oops - the button is enabled while the picker spins. I can't think of any way for the OP to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: @rmaddy On the second spin won't `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` be sent, which can be used to disable the button?

Comment: Oh, you mean use that event on the picker. I was thinking you meant on the button. Honestly, I don't know. I've never tried that event on a date picker. Then again, if the user simply taps the picker, you would end up disabling the button needlessly.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm just hacking a test project together now.  `UIControlEventTouchDown` doesn't work... looking for alternatives...

Comment: @rmaddy I've just tried `UIControlEventAllEvents` and even that isn't fired when the date picker is spun, so this isn't possible (not at least without some serious black magic).  The OP doesn't seem to care anyway, so I will be deleting this incorrect answer.

Comment: Don't delete the answer. Update it to summarize why it can't be done with a standard date picker.

Comment: @rmaddy These comments should serve as enough of an explanation. I think it can be done via subclassing, but not with the out-of-the-box `UIDatePicker`...

Comment: Ok thanks for yours answers, i finally solved by a textiles, when i click in, it is shown a DatePicker instead of keyboard